# Finding the location of a ROS node

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As part of my ROS re-education, I have been experimenting with the TurtleSim.
I understand that the following command:

```
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

..means execute **turtlesim_node** located in the **turtlesim** package. But I execute *roscd turtlesim* and listing the contents of that package, I can't locate the turtlesim node. The tree structure is shown below:

```
/opt/ros/melodic/share/turtlesim$ tree
.
├── cmake
│   ├── turtlesimConfig.cmake
│   ├── turtlesimConfig-version.cmake
│   ├── turtlesim-msg-extras.cmake
│   └── turtlesim-msg-paths.cmake
├── images
│   ├── box-turtle.png
│   ├── diamondback.png
│   ├── electric.png
│   ├── fuerte.png
│   ├── groovy.png
│   ├── hydro.png
│   ├── hydro.svg
│   ├── indigo.png
│   ├── indigo.svg
│   ├── jade.png
│   ├── kinetic.png
│   ├── kinetic.svg
│   ├── lunar.png
│   ├── lunar.svg
│   ├── melodic.png
│   ├── palette.png
│   ├── robot-turtle.png
│   ├── sea-turtle.png
│   └── turtle.png
├── msg
│   ├── Color.msg
│   └── Pose.msg
├── package.xml
└── srv
    ├── Kill.srv
    ├── SetPen.srv
    ├── Spawn.srv
    ├── TeleportAbsolute.srv
    └── TeleportRelative.srv
```

Can anyone help me understand how to pinpoint and locate the turtlesim, or any target, node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358306/finding-the-location-of-a-ros-node/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2020-07-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed turtlesim using `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-***` then it would be somewhere like this `/opt/ros/melodic/lib/turtlesim`. Roscd for installed packaged would take you to the include folder (I think).

If you `catkin_make`d the source code, then it would be in `devel/lib/`.

---

Originally posted by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) with karma: 257 on 2020-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2020-07-29**:
Thank you. It was in the directory you specified and not *roscd turtlesim*.
I found it but it didn't help my learning process as I hoped. The script is in binary.

**Comment by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on 2020-07-29**:
Yeah, it is an executable. But if you are looking to learn about the source code try https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials.